# c# Enum.ToString returns unexpected answer

Tags: c#, enums, tostring

To explain my problem, lets say that I have use an emum for so specify a country.
In the case of United Kingdom (enum 1 below) England, Wales etc must also refer to United Kingdom so are given the same value.

The problem occurs when I convert the enum to a string - whereby the result appears unpredicable.

Using the enum below, I would expect
country.UnitedKingdom.ToString()
to give
"UnitedKingdom".

Instead we get "Wales".
Futhermore, if we remove 'Scotland = UnitedKingdom', we get "England"!!

I have toyed with using Descriptions, but need these to convert the strings to the correct enum in the first place. eg:
[Description("Nothern Ireland")]
NothernIreland = UnitedKingdom,

Does anyone have an explanation as to why this happens and how possible to get arround it?

Thanks in anticipation

Fiv

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(country.UnitedKingdom.ToString());
    }
    
    enum country {
        Unknown = 0,
        UnitedKingdom = 1,
        France= 2,
        
        Wales = UnitedKingdom,
        England = UnitedKingdom,
        Scotland = UnitedKingdom,
    }
}
```

Comment: The behavior you observe is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring): "If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return." This is neither a correct way to use an enum, nor even a correct way of representing the countries of the UK. You may be looking for a dictionary instead.

Comment: If you take a look at the generated IL you will notice that the underlying integer value is passed to the `ToString()` method and not a specific enum field. It's impossible to accurately determine the correct string from this value as it maps to 4 different enum fields

Comment: A further problem with this approach is: How would you get to the correct enum value from an integer? What if you want to convert `int x = 1` to an `country y`? What would be the expected value for `y`?

Comment: "In the case of United Kingdom (enum 1 below) England, Wales etc must also refer to United Kingdom so are given the same value." The **also** makes me assume you have actually two information that you try to convert into a single one. You shouldn't use an enum in the first place.

Comment: If this is somehow a test how enums work (enums seems the wrong structure for this in the long run) you might want to have a look at Flags enums and define UnitedKingdom as the "sum" of it parts like `UnitedKingdom = Wales|England|Scotland`. This way they get distinguishable (so ToString works) and still you can do logics like "is Wales part of UnitedKingdom" with it.

Comment: Thanks people. Put like this, It's pretty obiouse why this couldn't work. I'll take your suggestions on board revise my solution :-)

Answer (score 5):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tostring?view=net-7.0):

> If multiple enumeration members have the same underlying value and you attempt to retrieve the string representation of an enumeration member's name based on its underlying value, your code should not make any assumptions about which name the method will return.

In other words: Your use case is not supported by the built-in `Enum` type. Variables store enum *values*, not enum *names*: You can think of `var c = country.Wales;` as assigning to `c` the information *"value 1 of enum country"*. The information about the concrete name used in your source code is "lost".

I don't know enough about your underlying problem to suggest an alternative, but, at first glance, the cleanest solution would probably be to only define `UnitedKingdom` in your enum and make the translation from input `England` to `UnitedKingdom` *before* converting the value to an enum.